# What electrode material can I use for electrical discharge machining?

Tags: discharge, electric-machine, spark, electrode, die

Can I use an electrode made of melted soldering wire in electrical discharge machining (EDM) instead of copper or graphite? I think it is very easy for me to make electrode by using melted soldering wire by casting. Will it work on  EDM?

Comment: Define EDM more thoroughly or provide links.

Comment: No . you must use a high temp material that burns the electrode slower than the target commonly used in EDM.

Comment: If you have access to melted solder, you have access to copper wire. Why not get a few inches of small-gauge copper wire? It's cheaper than solder and has 10 times better resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The deciding factors for choice of electrode material for an electrical discharge machine (EDM -  also known as a spark erosion machine) would be its conductivity and erosion resistance.

Copper and graphite are the most preferred materials.

One wouldn't come across lead or solder for this application and their wear resistance wouldn't be known unless trials are carried out.